# In FPGA, why counter with full adder raw implementation have better clock performance than infered addition '+'?

Tags: fpga, chisel, yosys, icestorm

I'm testing counter and addition performances on [ICE40](https://clifford.at/icestorm) and [Gatemate](https://colognechip.com/programmable-logic/gatemate/) FPGAs.

I wrote counter in two differents way :

1. `NaturalCounter` using the operator '+' of [chisel](https://www.chisel-lang.org/) ([view source](https://github.com/Martoni/PimpMyCounter/blob/main/src/main/scala/Blink.scala#L40C1-L51C2)):

```
// Natural counter with classic addition"
class NaturalCount(val COUNT_WIDTH: Int = 32) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val count = Output(UInt(COUNT_WIDTH.W))
  })

  val MAXCOUNT = BigInt(1) << COUNT_WIDTH
  val counterSize = log2Ceil(MAXCOUNT)
  val counterValue = RegInit(0.U(counterSize.W))
  counterValue := counterValue + 1.U
  io.count := counterValue 
}
```

2. `FullAdderCount` that is an instantiation of chained FullAdder described in Chisel [here](https://github.com/Martoni/PimpMyCounter/blob/main/src/main/scala/Blink.scala#L69).

```scala
/* FullAdder counter */
class FullAdderCount(val COUNT_WIDTH: Int = 32) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val count = Output(UInt(COUNT_WIDTH.W))
  })

  val counterValue = RegInit(0.U(COUNT_WIDTH.W))
  val addition = Module(new FullAdderAddition(COUNT_WIDTH))
  addition.io.a := counterValue
  addition.io.b := 1.U
  counterValue := addition.io.s

  io.count := counterValue
}
```

If I synthesis (and place&route) these counters in a [blinker](https://github.com/Martoni/PimpMyCounter/blob/main/src/main/scala/IcestickBlink.scala) with **ice40** using [icestorm](https://clifford.at/icestorm) tools (yosys and nextpnr) with a 44 bits counters I got these performances

- `NaturalCount`:

```
2.48. Printing statistics.

=== IcestickBlink ===

   Number of wires:                 14
   Number of wire bits:            240
   Number of public wires:          14
   Number of public wire bits:     240
   Number of memories:               0
   Number of memory bits:            0
   Number of processes:              0
   Number of cells:                130
     SB_CARRY                       42
     SB_DFF                         44
     SB_LUT4                        44

Info: Max frequency for clock 'clk$SB_IO_IN_$glb_clk': 117.32 MHz (PASS at 12.00 MHz)
Info: Max frequency for clock 'clk$SB_IO_IN_$glb_clk': 121.15 MHz (PASS at 12.00 MHz)
```

- `FullAdderCount`:

```
   Number of wires:                581
   Number of wire bits:            810
   Number of public wires:         581
   Number of public wire bits:     810
   Number of memories:               0
   Number of memory bits:            0
   Number of processes:              0
   Number of cells:                173
     SB_DFF                         44
     SB_DFFE                        43
     SB_LUT4                        86

Info: Max frequency for clock 'clk$SB_IO_IN_$glb_clk': 436.68 MHz (PASS at 12.00 MHz)
Info: Max frequency for clock 'clk$SB_IO_IN_$glb_clk': 380.37 MHz (PASS at 12.00 MHz)
```

`NaturalCount` version use less LUT than `FullAdderCount` but clock perfomances are far better with `FullAdderCount`.

Is it normal ? What is the purpose of SB_CARRY if the performance are slower than "normal" LUT ?

I tried the same with [Gatemate FPGA](https://github.com/Martoni/PimpMyCounter/blob/main/src/main/scala/GatemateBlink.scala) that is use same software for synthesis (yosys) but another "home made"  for place&route (p_r).

- `NaturalCount` with 44 bits counter on Gatemate :

```
2.49. Printing statistics.
 
=== GatemateBlink ===
 
   Number of wires:                 72
   Number of wire bits:            352
   Number of public wires:          24
   Number of public wire bits:     217
   Number of memories:               0
   Number of memory bits:            0
   Number of processes:              0
   Number of cells:                144
     CC_ADDF                        44
     CC_BUFG                         1
     CC_DFF                         44
     CC_IBUF                         2
     CC_LUT2                        44
     CC_OBUF                         8
     CC_PLL                          1

Maximum Clock Frequency on CLK 160 (160/3):  189.79 MHz
```

- `FullAdderCount` with Gatemate :

```
2.49. Printing statistics.
 
=== GatemateBlink ===
 
   Number of wires:                595
   Number of wire bits:            835
   Number of public wires:         506
   Number of public wire bits:     745
   Number of memories:               0
   Number of memory bits:            0
   Number of processes:              0
   Number of cells:                186
     CC_BUFG                         1
     CC_DFF                         87
     CC_IBUF                         2
     CC_LUT2                         2
     CC_LUT3                        85
     CC_OBUF                         8
     CC_PLL                          1

Maximum Clock Frequency on CLK 160 (160/3):  189.79 MHz
```

With this FPGA, the clock performances are exactly the same.

I wonder why clock performance isn't better when using the SB_CARRY and CC_ADDF cells with '+' instantiation.

Is it a "bug" in my design or is it normal ?

Comment: What do the actual layouts in the fabric look like? Do you get different results if you set a more stringent clock constraint that actually requires optimizing placement?

Comment: I don't know for the layouts. I tested all synthesis/place/route with default clock constraint for each FPGA. It's probable that changing clock constraint will change result.

Comment: If you actually start pushing the optimizer to optimize (by constraining the clock to, say, 300 MHz) does the ice storm performance catch up for the carry chain? (Xilinx tended to do that, since the optimizer would usually give up on optimizing further once it met the target, unless you had specific configuration options set for performance exploration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in fact it was a bug in my code. The FullAdder option was a pdchain fast counter as described on [opencore](https://opencores.org/projects/pcounter).

```scala
    case CounterTypes.FullAdderCount => {
      println("Generate FullAdderCount of " + COUNT_WIDTH + " bits")
      val counter = Module(new PdChain(COUNT_WIDTH)) // <---- wrong class instaciated
      io.leds := counter.io.count(counter.counterSize-1, counter.counterSize-LED_WIDTH)
    }
```

I [fixed the code](https://github.com/Martoni/PimpMyCounter/commit/72a9bfa35fe8f5da544f56ae0aee2e431b564931) and get worse timing performances with FullAdder as expected initially.

Sorry for the inconvenience, but asking this question allowed me to find the mistake.